# How to remove ppa

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dpkg, ppa

I'm accessing a linux system [Ubuntu16.04 LTS] remotely. A lot of things seem to be messed up. I need to install `libgmp-dev`, which gives `E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)` error. After trying a few things, I thought `apt-get update` might help, but `sudo apt-get update` gives error:

```
Err:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
404  Not Found
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Read a few posts and it seems removing the ppa is the solution, however I'm not sure how to do that from the command line. [This popular answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed) suggests `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge` before removing the ppa. But running `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge` again gives error `E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`.

I want to try the solution `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:whatever/ppa` but embarrassing enough I'm not sure what to put in place of `whatever` because I never installed these ppas (I only just got access to this system).

Output of `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d` is:

```
aheck-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list                 mc3man-ubuntu-xerus-media-xenial.list  nccl-2.1.15-ga-cuda8.0.list.save
aheck-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.save            multiverse.list                        opennms.list
blahota-ubuntu-texstudio-xenial.list         multiverse.list.save                   sublime-text.list
blahota-ubuntu-texstudio-xenial.list.save    myppa.list                             sublime-text.list.save
mc3man-ubuntu-trusty-media-xenial.list       myppa.list.save
mc3man-ubuntu-trusty-media-xenial.list.save  nccl-2.1.15-ga-cuda8.0.list
```

**EDIT:**

When I run `apt-get update` a lot of ppas from mc3man don't give any error, except the one (amd64), is it safe to remove all of these files which come as output of `grep mc3man *` inside `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`?

```
mc3man-ubuntu-trusty-media-xenial.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu xenial main
mc3man-ubuntu-trusty-media-xenial.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu xenial main
mc3man-ubuntu-trusty-media-xenial.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu xenial main
mc3man-ubuntu-trusty-media-xenial.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu xenial main
mc3man-ubuntu-xerus-media-xenial.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu xenial main
mc3man-ubuntu-xerus-media-xenial.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu xenial main
```

**EDIT2:**

`mv mc3man-ubuntu-trusty-media-xenial.list mc3man-ubuntu-trusty-media-xenial.list.bak` worked because I'm behind a proxy, now the error is:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to `cd` into the `sources.list.d` directory and run `grep` to a subpattern that you know from the error, such as:

`grep mc3man *`

this will show the file and line that it found that contains the given string, such as

`afile.list: blah/mc3man/blah`

you can then proceed with the `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:whatever/ppa` as proposed using the file where the string was matched (in this example, `afile.list`)

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot! Just added an edit to the question, can you please check before I proceed?

Comment: your error relates to the `http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu xenial/main` which is the first two lines of your output only ( `mc3man-ubuntu-trusty-media-xenial.list`).

Comment: Ran but gives `ERROR: '~mc3man-ubuntu-trusty-media-xenial.list' user or team does not exist.`

Comment: this indicates that either there is a network issue on your server or you are behind a proxy -- both scenarios are incompatible with `add-apt-repository`. You can simply move the `.list` files to backups (someone already did so with `.list.save`, so you can use `mv mc3man-ubuntu-trusty-media-xenial.list mc3man-ubuntu-trusty-media-xenial.list.bak` ). This should allow `apt` to work.

Comment: I am behind a proxy. This helped get rid of above error. However getting a different error `E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/` now.

Comment: try `sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock` to figure out if the lock file belongs to any process (if it does, either wait for it to end or `kill -9` it. If no process owns it, just `sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock`.